# Find all pages which have a parent

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How can I return all pages which have children?

So I have a standard table with

- pages.page_id
- pages.parent_id

So I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pages p 
WHERE COUNT(SELECT * FROM pages p2 WHERE p2.page_id = p.parent_id) < 0
```

Comment: A count will never be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can simply be solved using `JOIN`. The `DISTINCT` keyword was used in `SELECT` statement in order for the result list to be unique.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    pages a
        INNER JOIN pages b
            ON a.page_id = b.parent_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all pages which have children as follows:

```
select distinct(parent_id) from pages;
```

You could then use these parent ids to get the parent pages:

```
select * from pages,
             (select distinct(parent_id) as parent from pages) as parents
   where pages.page_id = parents.parent;
```

Answer (score 1):

to find the pages that have children pointing to them:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pages p 
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT * 
  FROM pages xx WHERE xx.parent_id = p.page_id
  );
```

To find the pages without any children change `EXISTS` to `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if thx syntax is completely correct, but i would do it with:

```
select * from pages where page_id not in 
(select page_id from pages where parent_id is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the IDs of the pages, there is no need to self-join the table. You can simply retrieve the values of the column parent_id. The SQL is something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent_id
FROM   pages
WHERE  parent_id IS NOT NULL
```